# dont want element stacking on top of each other

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

Im trying to horizontally slide in the second paragraph named contact-show over the first one named contact-list. That works now with position absolute and relative. 
But when I tried to insert the second div including the phone number, everything stacked on top of each other. I want them to be displayed like block element, over one and another. 
As far as i know, I'm using the position absolute to make the slide-effect work to get the second content to slide over the first one. If I don't have that they do not slide over on the same line.

```js
$('.contact-box').hover(function() {
  $('.contact-list').hide("slide", {
    direction: "left"
  }, 500);
  $('.contact-show').show("slide", {
    direction: "right"
  }, 500);
}, function() {
  $('.contact-show').hide("slide", {
    direction: "right"
  }, 500);
  $('.contact-list').show("slide", {
    direction: "left"
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.contact-box {
  position: relative;
}

.contact-show {
  display: none;
}

.contact-list,
.contact-show,
{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="page page-5">
  <h1 class="heading">Kontakta mig</h1>
  <div class="contact-box">
    <p class="contact-list">E-mail »</p>
    <p class="contact-show">bacon@hotmail.com</p>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-box">
    <p class="contact-list">Telefonnummer »</p>
    <p class="contact-show">073-000 00 00</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- end page-5 -->
```

Comment: Provide screenshot of the UI for us to understand.

Comment: There is an easier way to do this, without jquery: https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/zdLxrj

Comment: Thanks Kathara! But the reason I'm using jQuery is because the goal of this exercise is to learn more about jQuery. :)

Comment: Well, trying to avoid jQuery isn't that easy sometimes... look at it again. I changed it so that it will slide in from the side with pure css... if you want to learn about jquery, why don't you try a tutorial? codecademy is not so bad to learn: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery

Comment: Thanks. Looks awesome :) I have taken a few tutorials on teamtreehouse.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:absolute` and use `display:flex`, like this.

```css
.contact-box {
    position: relative;
    /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse; */
    height: 100px;
}
.contact-show{
  top:50px;
}
.contact-list, .contact-show {
   font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="page page-5">
    <h1 class="heading">Kontakta mig</h1>
    <div class="contact-box">
        <p class="contact-list">E-mail »</p><p class="contact-show">bacon@hotmail.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-box">
        <p class="contact-list">Telefonnummer »</p><p class="contact-show">073-000 00 00</p>
     </div> 
 </div> <!-- end page-5 -->
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think i need to use position absolute because the effect i want from jQuery is gonna work. I want the second paragraph to slide in over the first one from the right. And get all of the other information stacked under the first one, like a list or like block elements.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some fixed positions for your requirement, take a look.